# How to create a custom method for a given customRule in Aurelia Validation

Tags: typescript, aurelia

I am using aurelia-validation, and I created a customRule.

**Rule validation logic:**

```
export function validateCompare(value: any, obj: any, otherPropertyName: string) {
    return value === null ||
        value === undefined ||
        value === "" ||
        obj[otherPropertyName] === null ||
        obj[otherPropertyName] === undefined ||
        obj[otherPropertyName] === "" ||
        value === obj[otherPropertyName];
}
```

**Configuration:**

```
import { ValidationRules, validationMessages } from "aurelia-validation";
import { validateCompare } from "./compareValidation";

export function configureValidation() {
    validationMessages["required"] = "${$displayName} é obrigatório";
    validationMessages["email"] = "${$displayName} em formato inválido";

    ValidationRules.customRule("compare", validateCompare, "${$displayName} não confere com ${$getDisplayName($config.otherPropertyName)}", otherPropertyName => ({ otherPropertyName }));
}
```

**Using the customRule:**

```
ValidationRules
    .ensure((m: ClienteEdicaoViewModel) => m.Login).required().satisfiesRule("login")
    .ensure((m: ClienteEdicaoViewModel) => m.Senha).satisfiesRule("requiredIf", "ConfirmacaoSenha").satisfiesRule("senha")
    .ensure((m: ClienteEdicaoViewModel) => m.ConfirmacaoSenha).displayName("Confirmação de Senha").satisfiesRule("requiredIf", "Senha").satisfiesRule("compare", "Senha")
    .on(ClienteEdicaoViewModel);
```

**Question:**

I am using typescript, and I would like to create a method that wraps the use of the `satisfiesRule`, I would like to apply rules in this way:

```
ValidationRules
    .ensure((m: ClienteEdicaoViewModel) => m.Login).required().login()
    .ensure((m: ClienteEdicaoViewModel) => m.Senha).requiredIf("ConfirmacaoSenha").senha()
    .ensure((m: ClienteEdicaoViewModel) => m.ConfirmacaoSenha).displayName("Confirmação de Senha").requiredIf("Senha").compare("Senha")
    .on(ClienteEdicaoViewModel);
```

How can I create those `requiredIf` and `compare` methods and use it in the FluentRule?

C# has extensions methods that it would be able to do, but I tried some ways in typescript without no success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to augment the validation module and provide the implementation to the prototype.
This is what your configuration should look like.

```
import { ValidationRules, validationMessages, FluentRuleCustomizer, FluentRules } from "aurelia-validation";
import { validateCompare } from "./compareValidation";

export function configureValidation() {
    validationMessages["required"] = "${$displayName} é obrigatório";
    validationMessages["email"] = "${$displayName} em formato inválido";

    ValidationRules.customRule("compare", validateCompare, "${$displayName} não confere com ${$getDisplayName($config.otherPropertyName)}", otherPropertyName => ({ otherPropertyName }));
}

declare module "aurelia-validation/dist/commonjs/implementation/validation-rules" {
    interface FluentRules<TObject, TValue> {
        compare(value: string): FluentRuleCustomizer<TObject, TValue>;
    }

    interface FluentRuleCustomizer<TObject, TValue> {
        compare(value: string): FluentRuleCustomizer<TObject, TValue>;
    }
}

FluentRules.prototype.compare = function (value: string) {
    return this.satisfiesRule("compare", value);
};

FluentRuleCustomizer.prototype.compare = function (value: string) {
    return this.satisfiesRule("compare", value);
};
```

Comment: And thanks for the question BTW, it made my code better too :)

Comment: Thank so much, I was trying with `declare module "aurelia-validation"`, using the full location it worked, nicely done!!!!

Comment: fantastic answer